# How Do Perform Match-Replace-Match Next-Replace function in Excel?

Tags: excel, vlookup

I want to know what's the best approach/function/nested function to do the following:

I have 1 List with fixed data:

List items:

```
1001
1002
1003
1004
```

I have a table with contents:

```
Column A     
Column B       


Column A Title: Item Code     
Column B Title: Description
```

Column A Content:

```
Row 1: 1001    
Row 2: sc    
Row 3: nc    
Row 4: sc    
Row 5: 1002    
Row 6: nc    
Row 7: vc    
Row 8: fc    
Row 9: 1003
```

Column B Content:

```
Travel to Miami         
Food for Miami        
Tickets to Miami Concert     
Gas for Atlanta           
Atlanta sight seeing     
Atlanta EMT                  
Telephone bills            
Telephone cell
```

What I want to do:

I want a formula that says 'take the first item code that appears in column A, match it with the list; if it is in the list then fill it in every cell going down UNTIL YOU FIND A DIFFERENT ITEM CODE that matches an item code in the list, then repeat that one until you find another one that matches any of the codes in the list.'

So, the end result would be:

- In column A, the "sc" and "nc" after the 1001 would be replaced with "1001";
- Then excel would detect '1002' next, and replace 'nc' and bc' that follows with '1003' until it finds '1003';
- Then excel would detect '1004' and replace non-listed content with '1004' until it finds the next item that is in the list.

So far running an IFERROR formula only helps remove one content but does not detect the second number and automatically replace the second set of content with its respective number.

Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they're not necessarily in order, try this starting in C2:-

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A2,E$2:E$5,0)),C1,A2)
```

assuming the item codes start in row 2 of column A and the list is in E2:E5

[image]

Comment: This formula worked. Thanks Tom! The only thing is that I have to add a new column to run the function. Is there a way to run the function in the same column - say in column A starting row 2? I suspect it would end up being a loop error. ... But thanks for the help!

Comment: That's good! No sorry, I think you would need VBA to replace the values in column A.

Comment: One more step: I am now writing a macro to automate this all. My problem is  when macro is recording, I try to correct text/numbering error that came in from original sheet (Column A above); I select cell A2, and press Shift+Column A; this selects the entire column A; then I click the drop down menu to fix the error and select "convert to numbering"; the result is good enough to allow column C to do its operations. Then I stop recording the macro. When I run it, it does not fix the error I had fixed when I recorded it. Any thought on solution?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the data is in ascending order(the numbers). In that case I think the best solution would be to enter in a different column("C" maybe):

`=MAX(A$1:A1)`

And that´s all you need. Let me know if that´s useful.

Comment: Hi Santiago, my problem was that real document did not have the data in ascending order and I did not want to risk increasing the error margin by adding another task (to ascend and align data in all columns to sync together); Tom's approach resolved the problem with minimal action.